# Get RAW text with LineBreak in the text from contenteditable field in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.5

I try do my note-book in GWT
We have a field whose content is stored in the database.
How to transfer to the server user text with a linebreaks?
I use Document.get().getElementById("note_01").getInnerText() - 
it returns the text on single-line.
write:

```
1

2

3
```

got: 123,
but need RAW text copy with linebreaks....

```
1

2

3
```

or how to fill in this contenteditable field so it got a raw text?

---

upd: okay google.
I found solution: in this case just need use .getInnerHTML() and replace tags to \n on server-side. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getInnerText()` gives you just the text while `.getInnerHTML()` would include the HTML markup. If you use `<br>`-tags perhaps you have to replace them with `\n`, depending on your further usage of the text or the way you want to store it in the DB.

Is there a reason you are using GWT 2.5 (if you are starting the project from scratch - what it sounds like)?

Comment: yes, thank you, i have found a solution to your response. you just copied my answer to my question?) i use this version of GWT, because the new version did not work in my bundle at the moment when i started to work with GWT. but if i want to write a serious project - i will definitely try to update